# php form sending email, but not in correct way

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, email

My contact form on my web page finally send emails, but it doesn't send it in the proper format. Below is the email of what I am getting. I blurred out the email and organization for privacy reasons.

[image: updated email outcome]

Anyway, as you can see from the picture, the name, email, and message content that the person would've written in the contact form are in the subject line instead of the actual email box-- I wrote down jibberjabber when I was filling out the form to test it. Is there a way that I could format my code so that the message and the name that they wrote down is in the message box instead of the subject box, and the email gets sent from the person who put their email in the form. Any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
      <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required" style="color: #ffffff"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required" style="color: #ffffff"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required" style="color: #ffffff"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS-- I'll put it here just in case.

```
#contact {
  background-image: url(../images/contact-bg.jpg);
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#contact .heading {
  padding-top: 95px;
}

#main-contact-form {
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-info {
  text-align: left;
}

form {
  align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 1;
  box-shadow: none;
}

textarea.form-control {
  min-height: 180px;
  resize: none;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


ul.address {
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.contact-info ul li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.contact-info ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-submit {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Java Script

```
        (function ($) {
        var messages = {
            'progress': '<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending email...</p>',
            'success': '<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will contact you as early as possible.</p>',
            'error': '<p class="text-danger">Aw snap! Something didn\'t go right!</p>'
        };
        var $form = $('form#main-contact-form');
        var formStatus = $('<div class="form_status"/>');
        $form.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    formStatus.html(messages.progress).fadeIn().prependTo($form);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success === true) {
                        formStatus.html(messages.success);
                    } else {
                        formStatus.html(messages.error);
                    }
                    formStatus.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                },
                error: function () {
                    formStatus.html(messages.error).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
            });
        })
    })(jQuery);
```

PHP

```
    <?php
$to = 'changedfor@privacyreasons.xyz';
$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
$from = !empty($_POST['email']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) : $to;
$message = !empty($_POST['message']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['message']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';

$body = "Name: {$name}\r\nEmail: {$from}\r\nMessage: {$message}";

$body = wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n");

$headers = [
    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
    "From: $name <$from>",
    "Reply-To: <$from>",
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion()
];
    $subject = 'some subject';
$success = mail($to, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die(json_encode(['success' => $success]));
}

echo $success ? 'Sent Successfully.' : 'An error occurred';

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the subject parameter, read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Also, `'\r\n'` is not the same as `"\r\n"`

```
$subject = 'some subject';
$success = mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: I added your suggestions into my code, and this time, I didn't even get an email. Also, I edited my question to show your code.

Comment: I checked again, a little while later, thinking that maybe it took a while for the website to work, and this time I got an email. If you would look at my question, I updated the picture. I still get the same outcome, but at least the content of the message is in some sort of format. The message is still in the title, though.

Comment: show the updated PHP code too. I'd recommend trying something simpler, just have a page somewhere that doesn't do anything fancy but send an email, and make sure you follow the docs